# Shell findstr without pop up DOS window

Tags: excel, vba, shell, window, command-line-interface

In Windows 10, I have Excel VBA code that searches a text file for a value and returns match(es).

The problem is a DOS window pops up while it is executing. I do not want this window to appear (or if it has to appear, be minimized somewhere).

This is the working code that but shows the DOS window. It does a case insensitve search for USERNAME value in a text file. I need to get the results and read through them.

```vb
theCommand = "findstr /I /P "
theCommand = theCommand & " " & USERNAME & " " & ACTIVEEMPLOYEESLISTFILE

Set oShell = Nothing
Set oExec = Nothing
Set oOutput = Nothing
        
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set oExec = oShell.Exec(theCommand)
Set oOutput = oExec.StdOut

While Not oOutput.AtEndOfStream
    recordLine = oOutput.readline
    MsgBox recordLine
Wend
```

I want the DOS window to not appear or be minimized when running AND be able to read in the results (that are not returned in a file).

Comment: Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32297699/hide-command-prompt-window-when-using-exec

Comment: I found this similar question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32297699/hide-command-prompt-window-when-using-exec

Comment: If you're unable to hide the window then maybe you can instead use VBA to search the file?

Comment: I agree with Tim Williams - if you want to capture the results you would be better off reading the file in VBA - example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275040/search-for-string-in-text-file-in-vb-and-print-lines

Comment: As noted in references in other comments, you will need to use the `.Run` method and write the results to a temporary file, in order to be able to prevent that. You can use the `FileSystemObject` to read and then delete the temporary file.

Comment: Writing results to a file  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978738/write-results-into-a-text-file   Probably best to pass a full path for the output file and not just the file name.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
Sub TestSearch()
    
    Const OUTPUT_FILE As String = "C:\Temp\output.txt" 'file for results
    '2>&1 - capture stderr in same file as stdout
    Const CMD As String = "cmd.exe /c findstr /I /P ""<lookfor>"" ""<infile>"" > ""<resultsfile>"" 2>&1"
    Dim runThis As String
    'build the command by replacing tokens
    runThis = Replace(CMD, "<lookfor>", "failed")
    runThis = Replace(runThis, "<infile>", "C:\Temp\tester.log")
    runThis = Replace(runThis, "<resultsfile>", OUTPUT_FILE)
    Debug.Print runThis
    With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        .Run runThis, 0, True
    End With
    
    Debug.Print FileText(OUTPUT_FILE) 'show the results
    
End Sub

'return all the text from a file
Function FileText(pth)
    With CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject").OpenTextFile(pth)
        FileText = .readall()
        .Close
    End With
End Function
```